# Unable to run compiler from raspberry-pi-tools, cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: pi-zero-w, cross-compilation

Trying to follow instructions from https://blog.monotok.org/compile-locally-run-raspberry-pi-via-clion/ for building executables on my local machine for my raspberry pi.

I have downloaded raspberry pi tools from https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools and am simply trying to run the compiler on my Raspberry Pi Zero W. When I do so, I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/SoftwareDevelopment/lib/raspberry-pi-tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin $ ./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
-bash: ./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I am running raspbian pi.

Solution:

I ended up using localhost for my remote host in order to do the build using the cross-compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raspberrypi/tools repository contains a **cross**-compiler. The compiler runs on an x86 computer and generates ARM binaries that can be executed on the Raspberry Pi.

The cross-compiler itself is an x86 binary, it is not meant to be used on the Raspberry Pi itself.
To compile code on the Pi, use the `gcc` or `g++` binaries that are included with RPiOS.

Comment: That's part of what was confusing me, then. Why does it tell me to add a remote host? Maybe add the local computer as a remote host?

Comment: @Thom I'm afraid that that's something only the author of the article can answer. When you're running CLion on your computer, from that point of view the RPi is a remote host. I'm not sure what you mean by “adding the local computer as a remote host”.

Comment: Evidently, the author is using remote host as a hack to run a different compiler. I used an ssh localhost so it would still build on my local computer. If this is correct, it's even a worse article than I thought.